# How is 100BASE-T1 Full duplex?

Tags: ethernet, digital-communications

100BASE-T1 consists of a single differential pair of wires, using tri-state logic.

Everything I have found so far says that 100BASE-T1 is full duplex but nothing has explained how this actually works on 1 pair.

Even the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet#100BASE-T1) entry says that it is full duplex, and then directly underneath that entry describes how 100Base-T**2** is full duplex because it has 2 diff-pairs allowing for simultaneous RX and TX.

Can someone explain how the full duplex works on 100BASE-T1? I'm expecting it either to not be full duplex but meet some sort of technical requirements such that it can still claim that it is or some really cool tech that allows simultaneous RX and TX on the same diff pair.

Comment: The same way a telephone works on 2 lines, active cancellation of the signal you intended to transmit from the received signal.

Comment: [How were four wires replaced with two wires in early telephones?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/543433/how-were-four-wires-replaced-with-two-wires-in-early-telephones/543479#543479) <-- same principles involved.